# Usando IF ELSE JINJA2 Python e Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

estou iniciando o desenvolvimento web utilizando Python e Flask, estou tentando alterar a classe de uma TAG porem analisando o valor que estou passando para ser reinderizado segue abaixo como estou fazendo para tentar usar um IF ELSE para de acordo com o resultado imprimir na tela uma tag especifica

```
{% if {{df.11}} = 1 %}
    <i class="bi bi-emoji-sunglasses"></i>
{% else %}
    <i class="bi bi-emoji-dizzy"></i>
{% endif %}
```

este campo ira conter apenas 2 valores 1 e 200, se for 1 sera impresso a tag  senão a outra, porem quando tento rodar tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\02-database-manager\templates\stage.html", line 43, in template {% if {{df.11}}  %}:
```

Comment: Poderia postar como está passando a variável para o template?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o código fornecido existem alguns ajustes para serem feitos.

Para utilizar um comando condicional if na linguagem de template do jinja, devemos utilizar o comando de igualdade, desta forma devemos utilizar o operador de comparação (`==`). Desta forma o código corrigido seria:

```
{% if {{df.a11}} == 1 %}
    <i class="bi bi-emoji-sunglasses"></i>
{% else %}
    <i class="bi bi-emoji-dizzy"></i>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Olá, na verdade esta variável [{{df.10}}] esta vindo de um for que esta carregando estes dados no template.
`{% for df in dfs %}
    <tr>
     <td>{{df.0}}</td>
      <td>{{df.1}}</td>
     <td>{{df.9}}</td>
       <td>{{df.10}}</td>
/tr>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: o que preciso e pegar {{df.10}}  e verificar o valor dele se for 1 retorna a tag x , se for qualquer outro retorna outra tag.